# Access SQL report (beginners)

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I know that you can do this in Access, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I can get the information I want easily using a Pivot Table in Excel, but I'm trying to learn how to use Access.

So I have one large data set, with the Fields:

- Department
- Class
- Subclass
- Item
- Sales

I want to find the items that make up the top 70% of sales in each subclass.

In Excel, this is easy. I have Department in **Filters**, I have Class followed by Subclass followed by Item in **Rows**, and Sum of Sales in **Values**. Sort by ascending and use basic math to find the top 70%.

In Access, I'm sure it is also easy. I haven't gotten very far:

```
SELECT subclass, Sum[Sales]
FROM Table
WHERE Department = Youth
Order By Sum[Sales] Desc
```

So this gives me the sales of the top subclasses in the Youth department.

Some main questions:

1. How do I break it down by item?
2. How do I show multiple classes and subclasses?
3. How do I show the top 70%?
4. What's the best way to report multiple departments at a time?

I've attached a picture of a general report I am aiming for.

- Department examples: Boys and Girls
- Class examples: Tops
- Subclass examples: Short, Long, Fashion

[image]

Comment: Build a report using Grouping & Sorting features and aggregate calcs in report and group footer sections. Limiting to top 70% can be tricky and I've never attempted such criteria. Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider joining two different levels of aggregates, on at the *item* level and other at *subclass* level:

Item Aggregate Query

```
SELECT department, class, subclass, item, Sum(Sales) As SumSales
FROM myTable
GROUP BY department, class, subclass, item
```

Subclass Aggregate Query

```
SELECT department, class, subclass, Sum(Sales) As SumSales
FROM myTable
GROUP BY department, class, subclass
```

Join Query of Both Aggregates

```
SELECT i.department, i.class, i.subclass, s.SumSales As SubClassSales,
       i.item, i.SumSales As ItemSumSales
FROM itemAggQ AS i
INNER JOIN subclassAggQ s
   ON i.department = s.department AND i.class = s.class AND i.subclass = s.subclass
WHERE (i.SumSales / s.SumSales) >= 0.7
ORDER BY i.department, i.class, s.SumSales DESC, i.SumSales Desc
```

Finally, for your specific layout, build a report with join query as its recordsource and use [grouping/sorting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-f23301a1-3e0a-4243-9002-4a23ac0fdbf3) with `=SUM(...)` controls in group header/footers.